# Is it possible to make call between two emulator on different machines?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know that I can make a call between two emulator on same machine,
but is it possible to make a call between two emulator between two different machine.
If yes then how? If not then why?

Comment: doubtful "If not then why?" Because it has no cell phone network? I suppose it may be possible to implement some kind of VOIP system and trick the emulator system into thinking that it is a plain ole phone call, but there is such a limited use for this it likely was not worth the time. If you can find skype apk's on your emulator maybe you can make a call that way?

Comment: Not all Android devices are cell phones. There are plenty of tablet-like devices out there with Wi-Fi, for example. @Hellboy: have you thought of using TCP/IP sockets?